# textFieldShouldBeginEditing: Only Recognizes 1 textField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have two text fields in my interface. txtUser allows the user to enter their username and txtPass allows the user to enter their password. I have programmatically assigned tags in the viewDidLoad method. I use these tags in order to identify the different text fields. The issue is that the textFieldShouldBeginEditing method only recognizes txtPass, while ignoring the txtUser. Both of these variables are linked to their respective text fields, so that's not what's causing the issue. Below is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.txtUser.tag=10;
    self.txtPass.tag=20;

}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{ 

    if (textField.tag == 10){
        self.btnNext.enabled = YES;
        self.btnPrevious.enabled = NO;
    }else if(textField.tag == 20){
        self.btnNext.enabled = NO;
        self.btnPrevious.enabled = YES;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you setting the delegate for the text fields anywhere?

```
self.txtUser.delegate=self;
self.txtPass.delegate=self;
```

Also make sure you implement UITextFieldDelegate on your view controller.

```
@interface YourViewController: UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Comment: Thank you! I had already implemented the UITextFieldDelegate in my view controller, but I had not set the delegates for the text fields anywhere. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: @user3821693 - Glad you found a solution, but I'm confused.  The post says that the delegate "method only recognizes txtPass, while ignoring the txtUser".  This implies that the delegate was being called, (and is consistent with the tags not getting set).  No worries anyway, just confused.

Comment: @ansible It's funny you bring that up...actually I am working on this project with someone else and he actually had put self.txtPass.delegate=self in the viewWillAppear method for a reason that he does not remember. Haha. It's okay...thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

My semi-confident guess is that you've setup the delegate, but not the outlets, so the code that you think is assigning the tags is not working (assigning `.tag = 10` to nil).

The incoming tag is then zero (the default) for both fields, so the else branch in the delegate code is always running.

Fix by setting the outlets (or by setting the tags in IB).